# Update datagrid's GroupHeader when item property changes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core, data-binding

I'm having some difficulty updating a certain binding.

I have a class DeviceList that loads some devices, it inherits from ObservableCollection and is listed as a resource in my XAML:

```
<local:DeviceList x:Key="Devices" />
```

Then, I have a CollectionViewSource that uses this devicelist as source, and groups it by a property from the Device:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsDevices" Source="{StaticResource Devices}" Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="GroupId" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

A Datagrid binding to this CVS, which has a group header style:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsDevices}}">
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <DataGridRowsPresenter />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        bla bla
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And then finally the Group Header style in the resources:

```
<Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Expander IsExpanded="True" Background="White" Foreground="Black">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30">
                            <Border Margin="5" Width="20" Height="20" Background="{Binding Path=Items, Converter={StaticResource DeviceGroupToColorConverter}}" CornerRadius="10" />
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="3" Text="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource DeviceGroupToGroupTitleConverter}}" />
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="3" Text="{Binding ItemCount, Converter={StaticResource ItemCountToStringConverter}}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </Expander>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

As you can see, there's a Border there that binds to "Items". This is a property of "CollectionViewGroup": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup?view=netcore-3.1

Basically each of my devices has a property "Connection", and when this property changes, I would like to set the color of this border in the corresponding group header.

The binding works fine the first time, but after that the DeviceGroupToColorConverter isn't called anymore when a connection changes. Device implements INotifyPropertyChanged, but I have no idea how to propagate that event to CollectionViewGroup's Items property. In fact, I have no idea where CollectionViewGroup instances live. I only have access to the CollectionViewSource.

I would like to avoid refreshing the entire DataGrid. I've read that it resets my expanders and also, why refresh the entire datagrid when only a certain group's header should change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by changing the binding to a MultiBinding and adding a binding with a Source set to the DeviceList:

```
<Border Margin="5" Width="20" Height="20" CornerRadius="10">
    <Border.Background>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DeviceGroupToColorConverter}">
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource Devices}" Path="Devices" />
            <Binding Path="Name" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

the "Devices" property of the DeviceList class is a simple getter that returns "this":

```
public ObservableCollection<Device> Devices 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return this;
    } 
}
```

I let the DeviceList listen to any property changes on device, and invoke PropertyChanged on the "Devices" property of DeviceList to pass on this event to the MultiBinding.

I then use the Name binding in the MultiBinding to filter my devices based on the group that they're in. Now I don't need to refresh the whole grid and my performance is good.